# Error: The argument type 'void Function(MidiDevice)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(List<MidiDevice>?)'

Tags: flutter, dart, future, midi

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to get familiar with the flutter_midi_command package. I have an `ElevatedButton` and I want to print the list of available MIDI devices on click.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => MidiCommand().devices.then((MidiDevice midiDevice) => print(midiDevice)),
  child: const Text('Show available MIDI devices'),
)
```

But in the `.then` part, I am getting the following error as soon as I define the type of the returned value from the callback:

```
The argument type 'void Function(MidiDevice)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(List<MidiDevice>?)'.
```

And but when I remove the type (`MidiDevice`), the error is removed. I believe I am missing a core concept from Dart/Flutter. My question is, how I am able to simply make this callback function to work when I have the type of the returned value defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my question. The type of the returned value is not `MidiDevice`, its `List<MidiDevice>?`.

The following is the correct implementation:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () => MidiCommand().devices.then((List<MidiDevice>? midiDevice) => print(midiDevice)),
  child: const Text('Show available MIDI devices'),
)
```